# Use a string as a formulae in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I am building up a formulae based on values set up ion a parameter sheet in the spreadsheet.  I now want to vealuate the formulae in VBA but don't know how to take the string and convert it into code instead of a string.

So the formulae is built up in code as follows (varies according to options, this is just a simple addition where the workbooks, sheets and cells are all variable for both terms)

```
CalculationHoldArray(Loopcount) = "'[" & Usefile1.Name & "]" & Worksheet1 & "'!" & Cells1 & ", + '[" & Usefile2.Name & "]" & Worksheet2 & "'!" & Cells2
```

The resulting string is in this case is

```
"'[Control Model v1.35- nonfunctional.xlsm]Input'!E2, + '[Control Model v1.35- nonfunctional.xlsm]Input'!E3"
```

How would I convert this to code?  I have tried doing it as an application.worksheet.sum function, but that gives an error.  In addition to the sum, I also need to be able to multiplication, division, subtraction and sumproduct for arrays.  I thought that using application.worksheet.sum function would work, but I just get errors

Comment: It appears you want to prepare and calculate `Excel-style` formula in VBA code directly?

Comment: Yep, not sure if it is the best way or if loading the values into variable and evaluating that way would be better.  The problem is that I am building the formulaes up first and then they will be used to evaluate 10,000 rows to build up a set of results.  So initially i need the formulaes as strings- if I then want to evaluate as code instead of satring I will convert it manually later, as each row is evaluated, rather than just adjusting what the cell and row reference.  These ones are just for the purpose of building up the formulae and giving the starting point for the first calculation

Comment: @MarcL Please accept the answer with `Evaluate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Application.Evaluate("Sheet1!A1 + Sheet1!A2")`

Note that there's a limit of 255 characters for the string expression you're evaluating.

[Documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx)

Comment: [For getting around the 255 char limit see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64696971/6302131)