# How do I write this evaluate formula so that the variant doesn't return an error?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a formula that works perfectly when used in a With / End With statement for the range:

`.Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(" & MasterDataRange.Address(External:=True) & ",MATCH(" & Cells(iRow, Entry1).Address(True, False) & "&Left(" & Cells(iRow + 1, Entry2).Address(False, False) & ", 4)&""" & wks4.Range("L7").Value & """," & MasterRowMatchRange.Address(External:=True) & ",0),MATCH(""" & header01 & """," & MasterColumnMatchRange.Address(External:=True) & ",0)),0)"`

When trying to Evaluate the above and assign it to a Variant, the Variant returns an error result 'Error 2015'.

`xResult = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(" & MasterDataRange.Address(External:=True) & ",MATCH(" & Cells(iRow, Entry1).Address(True, False) & "&Left(" & Cells(iRow + 1, Entry2).Address(False, False) & ", 4)&""" & wks4.Range("L7").Value & """," & MasterRowMatchRange.Address(External:=True) & ",0),MATCH(""" & header01 & """," & MasterColumnMatchRange.Address(External:=True) & ",0)),0)")`

Can someone help me understand this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you use `Worksheet.Evaluate` and not `Application.Evaluate`.

Comment: I changed the code to `xResult = Worksheet.Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(" & MasterDataRange.Address(External:=True) & ",MATCH(" & Cells(iRow, Entry1).Address(True, False) & "&Left(" & Cells(iRow + 1, Entry2).Address(False, False) & ", 4)&""" & wks4.Range("L7").Value & """," & MasterRowMatchRange.Address(External:=True) & ",0),MATCH(""" & header01 & """," & MasterColumnMatchRange.Address(External:=True) & ",0)),0)")` and the following error returns: Run-time error '424': Object Required.

Comment: What's also interesting is that when I code `xResult = Evaluate("=SUM(10,20,30)")` the xResult returns the expected result of 60.

Comment: You need a reference to the `Worksheet` that this formula is supposed to be evaluated against... see the [`Worksheet.Evaluate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.evaluate) docs.

Comment: Try removing the `=` at the beginning of your formula.

Comment: Incidentally, the formula worked with and without the '='.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging around, it turns out that there's a 255 character limit to the vba Evaluation Method, plus there I needed to remove some string references utilised by the .Formula Method

Thanks for the help. For those interested, the code is now:

```
    Set cell = wks4.Range("L7")
    On Error Resume Next
    rResult = Evaluate("MATCH(" & Cells(iRow, Entry1).Address(True, False) & "&" & "Left(" & Cells(iRow + 1, Entry2).Address(False, False) & ", 4)" & "&" & cell.Address(External:=True) & "," & MasterRowMatchRange.Address(External:=True) & ",0)") 'Match Header
    cResult = Evaluate("MATCH(""" & header01 & """," & MasterColumnMatchRange.Address(External:=True) & ",0)")  'Match Column
    xResult = Evaluate("INDEX(" & MasterDataRange.Address(External:=True) & "," & rResult & "," & cResult & ")")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If IsError(xResult) Then 'Handle Error 2042 = #N/A
        Range(Cells(iRow, iCol), Cells(iRow, iCol)) = 0
    Else:
        Range(Cells(iRow, iCol), Cells(iRow, iCol)) = xResult
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you can't get around the 255 character limit of formulae without writing the formulaes directly to cells. Excel's newer evaluation engine doesn't have the same limitations that the old one does (the one which is used by `Application.Evaluate`. A working prototype of a function which evaluates >255 char limit is as follows:

```
Function EvaluateAny(ByVal sFormula as string) as variant
    static evaluatorCell as Range: if evaluatorCell is nothing then set evaluatorCell = Range("...")
    if len(sFormula) > 255 then
        evaluatorCell.formula = sFormula
        evaluatorCell.Calculate
        EvaluateAny = evaluatorCell.value
    else
        EvaluateAny = Application.Evaluate(sFormula)
    end if
End Function
```

> Note: This method will be significantly slower than Application.Evaluate()

Another alternative would be to use [`stdLambda`](https://github.com/sancarn/stdVBA/blob/master/src/stdLambda.cls) so you have a more direct implementation of your formula:

```
Dim func as stdLambda: set func = stdLambda.Create("$1 > 10")
Debug.Print func(100) 'true
Debug.Print func(5)   'false
```

You'll need to include stdICallable interface if you go down this route.